Hotkey deamon that can deal with single presses of cntrl/super/alt?
I have been using the sxhkd hotkey deamon together with bspwm. But unfortunately, sxhkd doesn' seem to be able to deal with the setup where the cntrl/super/alt keys are used as both modifiers and single keypress hotkeys:
Hotkey 1: super (or Super_L)
Hotkey 2: super + Return

When super is pressed-down, then return is pressed and released, hotkey 2 should fire, but hotkey 1 shouldn't

When super is pressed, and then released and no other key is pressed in the meantime, hotkey 1 should fire.


Some people have suggested using xcape together with sxhkd, but this seems messy to me. Is there a hotkey deamon for linux that can just do this by itself, without requiring an extra tool like xcape?
